# How to manage JDK lifecycle?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

Curious to know how others manage JDK upgrades for WebLogic. ie if I need to upgrade from jdk1.8 update 100 to say jdk1.8 update 200, how would I go about doing this ?
One way is to install the new jdk in a new folder and then reconfigure entire weblogic to point to the new folder.
Other way is to install the new jdk in a command folder (say `/opt/java`) and then not have to reconfigure entire weblogic.
There is always the frowned upon "symlink" way, wherein you install java in `/opt/java-1.8-u100` and symlink it to `/opt/java`

Comment: The recommanded way (by Oracle) is to create and use a symlink. You install your jdk at any place, create a symlink and use it in your domain configuration. Next jdk updates will not require to update your domain configuration.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin Add that as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommanded way (by Oracle) is to create and use a symlink. You install your jdk at any place, create a symlink and use it in your domain configuration. Next jdk updates will not require to update your domain configuration

Answer (score 0):

You can install new JDK in any folder of your choice update `JAVA_HOME` in your `setDomainEnv.sh`.

If you want it in your PATH then you can set it in your `.bash_profile`.